# Is there a way to force a type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, mongoose, types

I have this:

```js
      const res: any = await table.find({}).toArray();
      const data: Type[] = res;
```

Is there a way to do something like this:

```js
      const res: Type[] = await table.find({}).toArray();
```

without the error : `Type 'Document[]' is not assignable to type 'Type[]'.` ?

Comment: I think you should use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Type Guards and Differentiating Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

If you are sure that `res` always will be array of `Type`, you can force type using `as`:

```
const res = await table.find({}).toArray() as Type[]; // res: Type[] now
```